# How to deal with network data packets in a client/server application code?

Tags: c#, client-server, marshalling

I'm creating a client/server application using C# and I would like to know the best approach to deal with data packets in C# code.

From what I read I could A) use the Marshal class to construct a safe class from a data packet raw buffer into or B) use raw pointers in unsafe context to directly cast the data packet buffer into a struct and use it on my code.

I can see big problems in both approaches. For instance using Marshal seems very cumbersome and hard to maintain (compared to the pointer solution) and on the other hand the use of pointers in C# is very limited (e.g. I can't even declare a fixed size array of a non-primitive type which is a deal breaker in such application).

That said I would like to know which of these two approaches is better to deal with network data packets and if there is any other better approach to this. I'm open to any other possible solution.

PS.: I'm actually creating a custom client to an already existing client/server application so the communication protocol between client and server is already created and can not be modified. So my C# client need to adhere to this already existing protocol to its lower level details (eg. binary offsets of each information in the data packets are fixed and need to be respected).

Comment: Frankly you shouldn't be decoding socket data via marshallers. You should be writing a protocol handler that looks at the byte stream fairly manually, taking what the protocol needs. Protocols rarely match marshalling requirements, and that is before even discussing endianness, encodings, etc. Btw c# totally supports fixed sized buffers of non-primitives - they're called "fixed buffers"

Comment: @MarcGravell one thing I forgot to say is that I'm actually developing a custom client to an existing application. Considering this do you think I could still write a "protocol handler" to work this out? (never read anything about writing a custom protocol handler)

Comment: I have a 4-part blog series that discusses modern approaches for this that might be useful, starting: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html

Comment: @MarcGravell I'll take a read! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are dealing with two of the 7 layer of a Network.  1) Transport layer where you are sending data serially over a stream (TCP or UDP).   Which is what Marc link is describing.  2) Application Layer where you have a class object that you want to send/receive.  So you really are asking about the application layer of converting a class to bytes and bytes to class.  c# is a managed library the doesn't easily allow the conversion between bytes to/from class.

Comment: Microsoft designed the c# managed library to eliminate a blue screen crash that often occurred in windows  before Win XP (win 95, win 98, win 2000, win ME, WinNt).  The blue screen error often occur when pointer where not configured properly.  So When Net 3.5 (same time as Win XP) made it nearly impossible to use pointers and added lots of checks in the managed library to prevent Blue Screen Exception.  The Marshal library have the checking to prevent Blue Screen while unsafe mode does not have the checking.

Comment: @jdweng so C# wouldn't be the best language to develop the application I'm developing? What about more common scenarious where both the client and the server being developed from ground up; it is hard for me to imagine how this cli/srv would handle the protocol of the application layer considering they need to pass complex classes to each other through the network - what could be done in this case? May you please throw any words to ease my research on the subject?

Comment: @MarcGravell I just read your comment about C# supporting fixed sized buffers of non-primitive types. May you tell me how I can find any docs about that? All texts I find about this points out you can not declare fixed size buffers of non-primitive types. The compiler also complains saying only primitive types can be used on fixed buffers.

Comment: There are many reasons for choosing a programming language.  The people who run this website often close postings when OP ask for recommendations.  I do not know your requirements, experiences, or feature you want in you application so I'm avoiding answering the BEST language.  I do not like a lot of features in c#, but also know the language very well and use it as my primary programming language.

Comment: @jdweng I understand your concerns but I was simply asking if you were saying C# could not handle my specific case very well (ie. there is no language-specific way to handle my problem).

Comment: c# is not the most efficient language of casting objects to bytes (need to send/receive).  You can use binary serialization for the casting.  If you need more efficient code then use c++.

Comment: @underthevoid ah, indeed; my apologies - there are way of *hacking around* that, but they're probably not things I should advertise; it involves hacking around with forced coercions (over either pointers or spans)

Comment: @MarcGravell are you talking about declaring a fixed size buffer of primitives and casting it to a struct ref returning a given index from the buffer?

Comment: @underthevoid more or less, yes - if you `Unsafe.AsRef` inside the `fixed` you can coerce a `Foo*` to a `ref Foo` "interior pointer" (having coerced a `byte* to a Foo*`) - all evilness

Answer (score 0):

the best approach to deal with network packets. you have to create the Payload attached to the header of actual packet and you receiving client always first read the header and convert it to the actual length. then set the buffer length that you received in the header. it will perfectly work without any loss of packets. it will also improve the memory leakage issue. you don't need to create the hard coded array to get the buffer bytes. just append the actual byte length to the header of packet. it will dynamically set the buffer bytes.

like.

```
  public void SendPackettoNetwork(AgentTransportBO ObjCommscollection, Socket Socket)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] ActualBufferMessage = PeersSerialization(ObjCommscollection);
            byte[] ActualBufferMessagepayload = BitConverter.GetBytes(ActualBufferMessage.Length);
            byte[] actualbuffer = new byte[ActualBufferMessage.Length + 4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(ActualBufferMessagepayload, 0, actualbuffer, 0, ActualBufferMessagepayload.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(ActualBufferMessage, 0, actualbuffer, ActualBufferMessagepayload.Length, ActualBufferMessage.Length);
            Logger.WriteLog("Byte to Send :" + actualbuffer.Length, LogLevel.GENERALLOG);
            Socket.Send(actualbuffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteException(ex);
        }
    }
```

**Just pass your transport class object. use you serialization approach here i used binary formatter serialization of class object**